# Windows 10 Deployment by WIM image

Tags: windows-10, deployment, wim

**Background**: A long time ago, I followed a guide to create a Windows 7 disk image.  The image has all the software my users need pre-installed.  I put the WIM image on a USB drive, and, together with `imagex.exe`, I am able to install the image on new machines in about 15 minutes.  There's still a little bit of setup to do to get all the right drivers installed, but the whole process takes about half an hour for most machines.

**My question**: I am looking to create a similar disk image for Windows 10, but I am unable to find a definitive guide for my scenario/use case.  My understanding is that because of the Windows App store, deploying Windows 10 is substantially different from Windows 7.

What are my options?

Answer (score 0):

Slipstreaming Windows 10 is very similar to slipstreaming Windows 7.

In Windows 7 you used N-Lite to create a slipstreamed windows installation, whereas in Windows 10 you can use [NT-Lite](https://www.ntlite.com/download/) to do the same. The steps are similar for both programs.

With windows 10, you start by downloading the [Media Creation Tool](https://www.microsoft.com/software-download/windows10), and instead of updating your current install, you choose to create an ISO file. Once you have the ISO, use a program such as [7-zip](https://www.7-zip.org/) to extract the ISO to a folder. This will become your workfolder. From NTLite, you can now load this new folder to create your WIM image. You can even add programs during the install, set specific options, etc... NTLite will guide you through all of it.

At the very end, you can save your new version as ISO. The new ISO can then be used to create a bootable USB stick by using [Rufus](https://rufus.akeo.ie/).

Keep in mind, test your version of the installer to determine that it exactly what it should do. You can use something like Oracle VM to install your new windows install by attaching the ISO directly to the Virtual Machine and booting from it.

Comment: Worth pointing out that `imagex.exe` has been discontinued for years.  DISM took its place when Windows 8 was released.  How you create a `.wim` image of your machine is basically the same.  `NT-LIte` is just one tool to manipulate the DISM syntax into doing what you want.  The same instructions you used for Windows 7 can be used, just replace the `imagex.exe` commands with the DISM commands.

Comment: @Ramhound sounds like an answer to me. I have no experience with imagex.exe nor how to do that with DISM, so feel free to provide an answer on your own. All I know is that NT Lite converts the esp image to wim, and then works with it.

Comment: It really isn't an answer, it's just pointing out the method to create your own Windows image has not actually changed, only the syntax has changed.